# How to transfer control from one control to another

Tags: c#, wpf

I created next WPF controls : Window1, View, Edit in different files:

In MainWindow.xaml `MainWindow` contein two ContentControls

```
    <Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Viewer" Content="ContentControl1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Editor" Content="ContentControl2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

This is part of **.cs** file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        View v = new View();
        Edit e = new Edit();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Window1.Viewer.Content = v;
            Window1.Editor.Content = e;
        }
        public  void swichToEditor()
        {
            Window1.Editor.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Window1.Viewer.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public void swichToViewer()
        {
            Window1.Ediort.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            Window1.Viewer.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }
```

`ComtentControl1` with `x:name=Editor` contain this userControl:

```
    public partial class Edit : UserControl
        {
            public Edit()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

            }
        }
```

`ComtentControl2` with `x:name=Viewer` contain this userControl:

```
    public partial class View : UserControl
        {
            public View()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Button2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            }
        }
```

When `button1` will be pressed i need that `Editor` will be hide and `Viewer` will be visible. and vice-versa
I know better c++ syntax. and signal-slot method closer to me :)
What your advice to me?

Comment: Your post is unreadeable, you should format it in a better way. Moreover, did you write any code? Can you show it?

Comment: Thank you II Vic for your advice? I hope now it's more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RoutedEvent's behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx). You just need to register your Window to the Click RoutedEvent. Take a look:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    View v = new View();
    Edit e = new Edit();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Window1.Viewer.Content = v;
        Window1.Editor.Content = e;

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(GetType(), Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClick));
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is View)
        {
            SwichToEditor();
        }
        else
        {
            SwichToViewer();
        }
    }

    public void SwichToEditor()
    {
        Window1.Editor.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Window1.Viewer.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public void SwichToViewer()
    {
        Window1.Ediort.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        Window1.Viewer.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Then you do not need to have a button click event handler in your UserControls.

I hope this sample can help you.